# What is the best way to start thousands of Tasks in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

Lets say I have a `List` of users, and I want to perform some operation on all of them, such as updating one of their properties in a database. The list of users can potentially contain tens or hundreds of thousands of users. If all of the work to be done to the users was local to my machine, then I would just use `Parallel.ForEach` to process them, but because this will involve waiting (potentially many seconds) for a call to an external service to complete, I think it's more appropriate to use `Task`s.

Right now, this is the code that I have:

```
        Task.WaitAll(usersList.Select(user => Task.Run(() => async
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            try
            {
                await UpdateUserInExternalService(user);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError($"Something went wrong with user 'user.Username'.", ex);
            }
        }, cancellationToken)).ToArray());
```

I have some questions:

1. If the list has 10,000 users in it, does it actually create 10,000 tasks all at once (huge memory spike)? Or does it just create, say 10, and then as some tasks complete the others are spun up?
2. Is how I am using the cancellation token look correct?
3. If I cancel the operation right away after invoking it, does it still have to spin up all 10,000 tasks before they are cancelled, or is that avoided because I am passing the cancellation token into the Task.Run parameters?

In my testing it seems to work well. I just want to make sure there isn't anything I'm overlooking or some gotcha that I am likely to encounter, or if there's a best-practice that I'm not following.

I'm open to any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

### Update

As per the comments, I do not have any control over the external service or its database. I only have the call they provide to me, which takes a single user. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to use a less chatty interface that can update many users at once?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan Unfortunately not. And you can ignore the specific use-case I've presented here. I'm more interested in the best-practice methods to starting up thousands of tasks.

Comment: Well, one solution to the use case is *not* to start all those tasks but rather to redesign the interface. :-)

Comment: It would be much more efficient to let the database perform these operations, e.g. the UpdateUserInExternalService should really be invoking an `UPDATE x FROM users WHERE UserID IN [your users]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions AvnerShahar-Kashtan and @Simon. Unfortunately I do not have any control over the external service, its interface, or its database.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this code would start all operations at once. The `Task.Run` does not do much. Since this is using async IO the thread pool has little involvement. It will not throttle this.

Don't do this. Likely, this will overload some resource. Use the last piece of code from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/. Such a thing should be in the framework because almost always is it necessary to pick an exact degree of parallelism for IO work.

(3) does not matter after the fix is applied. Before the fix the token has almost no impact because all operations are started immediately causing the token to be checked only once immediately. After that cancellation is no longer possible.

You can also pass the token to `UpdateUserInExternalService` to achieve even more immediate cancellation.

Comment: I upvoted this, but haven't marked it as the answer yet, as I want to see if others can provide a better/different alternative. The one thing I don't like about the Partition method is I still need to define the MaxDegreeOfParallelism. I was hoping there would be a built-in "automatic" way of the PC calculating the ideal # for me. A simpler alternative to the Partition method mentioned in your link, would be to instead use Parallel.Invoke and provide a MaxDegreeOfParallelism. It takes Actions instead of Tasks, but that's an easy conversion to do, with less complicated code IMO.

Comment: There is no way to calculate the optimal DOP for IO. It depends on your hardware, the network and on everything inside of the service you are calling. It is entirely unrelated to the CPU count in the client machine. You are best off empirically determining a DOP and configuring it. Parallel.* does not allow you to set the min DOP making it unsuitable for IO. You want exact DOP.

Comment: This - I mean the S.Toub solution on the link in the answer - is exactly how you should do it. It mixes the parallel and async/await paradigm the correct way.

Comment: @MiklósTóth you are right. It's like 10 questions per week that are caused by this primitive missing in the framework. Many people don't understand that async IO does not free them from resource management.